# Get a value for the last entry of a day

Tags: excel, date, datetime, formula, dax

I have a list of values, with several entries per day, spanning several days. I'd like, for each day, to get the max, min and the last values. I'm using additional column as I didn't find a way to use a measure.

Here is a sample of data:

| date | marge | date (Day) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/1/2021 9:31 | 832,95 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 9:54 | 670,95 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 10:15 | 815,65 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 10:36 | 890,65 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 10:57 | 836,9 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 11:18 | 912,4 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 11:40 | 1149,25 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 12:01 | 1339,15 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 12:22 | 1449,3 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 12:43 | 1659,2 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 13:04 | 1502,6 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 13:25 | 1357,3 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 13:46 | 1508,85 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 14:07 | 1427,65 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 14:29 | 1408,05 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 14:50 | 1421,1 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 15:37 | 1398,85 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 15:51 | 1410,85 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 16:11 | 1089,2 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 16:32 | 1130,55 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 16:54 | 1111,45 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 17:15 | 1134,9 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 17:36 | 1274,85 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 17:57 | 1384,75 | 01-févr |
| 2/1/2021 18:18 | 1384,75 | 01-févr |
| 2/2/2021 10:23 | 761,2 | 02-févr |
| 2/2/2021 10:44 | 955,55 | 02-févr |
| 2/2/2021 12:58 | 622,85 | 02-févr |
| 2/2/2021 13:17 | 668,9 | 02-févr |
| 2/2/2021 15:16 | 754,1 | 02-févr |
| 2/2/2021 16:32 | 735,7 | 02-févr |
| 2/2/2021 16:45 | 722,25 | 02-févr |
| 2/2/2021 17:05 | 693,15 | 02-févr |
| 2/2/2021 17:26 | 699,05 | 02-févr |
| 2/2/2021 17:48 | 644,6 | 02-févr |
| 2/2/2021 18:09 | 594,9 | 02-févr |
| 2/2/2021 18:30 | 594,9 | 02-févr |
| 2/3/2021 10:56 | 513,65 | 03-févr |
| 2/3/2021 11:15 | 468,65 | 03-févr |
| 2/3/2021 11:35 | 518,25 | 03-févr |
| 2/3/2021 11:56 | 643 | 03-févr |
| 2/3/2021 12:16 | 584 | 03-févr |
| 2/3/2021 12:36 | 656,75 | 03-févr |
| 2/3/2021 12:56 | 685,85 | 03-févr |
| 2/3/2021 13:16 | 773,7 | 03-févr |
| 2/3/2021 13:36 | 755,15 | 03-févr |
| 2/3/2021 13:56 | 608,95 | 03-févr |
| 2/3/2021 14:16 | 622,6 | 03-févr |
| 2/3/2021 14:36 | 580,5 | 03-févr |
| 2/3/2021 14:56 | 591,1 | 03-févr |
| 2/3/2021 15:30 | 513,35 | 03-févr |
| 2/3/2021 16:56 | 354,95 | 03-févr |
| 2/3/2021 17:30 | 630,05 | 03-févr |
| 2/3/2021 17:58 | 625,2 | 03-févr |
| 2/4/2021 9:38 | 524,2 | 04-févr |
| 2/4/2021 10:04 | 603,9 | 04-févr |
| 2/4/2021 10:24 | 668,2 | 04-févr |
| 2/4/2021 11:05 | 612,7 | 04-févr |
| 2/4/2021 11:28 | 654,45 | 04-févr |

So for the min and max, I have the following formulae:

```
CALCULATE(MAX(intradays[marge]); FILTER(intradays; intradays[date (Day)]=EARLIER(intradays[date (Day)]))
```

which works correctly (MIN for min)

However, to get the last for each day is a completely different story. I have no idea how to achieve this.

The values I'm looking for are:
Last for the 1st of Feb : 1384.75
Last for the 2nd : 595.9
Last for the 3rd : 652.2

P.S.: using 365.

Comment: In PowerQuery you could group by Date; then return the max, min and last values for each sub-table. Not sure about DAX, though

Comment: Try using MATCH to find the next day. The last will then be the row before the one you found.

Comment: Please use [markdown tables](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to insert your data into the question via [edit]. The link I shared has the option to copy paste data from Excel and generate a markdown table. Paste that into your question, highlight all that you just pasted and press Ctrl + K. That way we can copy your data for testing rather than trying to recreate from an image (or moving on due to effort involved before actually addressing the question)

Comment: I think you could get this to work with MINIFS with a little bit of tinkering https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-minifs-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a model consisting of a single table (and no dimensions) you must take care of the filtering columns involved.

This is a measure that first finds the max date keeping the filter over intradays[date (Day)] and then finds the corresponding Marge, filtering only the intradays[date] column.

The MAX is used to avoid an error in case there were two identical timestamps.

```
LastMarge = 
VAR maxDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( intradays[date] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( intradays, intradays[date (Day)] )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'intradays'[marge] ),
        intradays[date] = maxDate,
        REMOVEFILTERS ( intradays )
    )
```

The column can be created using the measure, like for instance

```
LastMargin = [LastMarge]
```

Answer (score 1):

I created this table with one additional calculated column

```ml
DateOnly = FORMAT(Table1[date],"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

[image: format date]

Then created 3 measures:

```ml
margeMax = MAX(Table1[marge])

margeMin = MIN(Table1[marge])

margeLast = CALCULATE(
    VAR _maxDateTime = MAX(Table1[date])
    RETURN MAXX(FILTER(Table1, Table1[date] = _maxDateTime), Table1[marge])
)
```

The resulting table visualization:
[image: resulting table visualization]

Comment: thank you Zygd, it works as a measure but if i'm copying the margeLast formula into an additional column, each row is considered the last